# Vim outputting weird characters and becoming unresponsive

Tags: terminal

I'm using Vim inside gnome-terminal. Every so often, typically after coming back to a file opened in a vim session in another terminal tab after editing some other file opened in some other vim session in some other terminal tab, the Vim session in the first terminal tab won't take any command, and I have to quit it with `:q!` and reopen it before I can do anything.

The above, as suggested by a comment below, is not exactly clear, so, to make it clearer:

I'm using gnome-terminal. Gnome terminal has tabs, opened with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Sometimes I open a file in Vim in one terminal tab (it's not a vim tab, but a terminal tab), while editing another file in vim in another terminal tab. It's a separate vim session because they're different terminal tabs. (I'm mentioning this because I know vim tabs aren't tabs per se, but 'view ports', sharing all buffers. So I'm talking about two separate instances of Vim, independent of each other:

- one instance running in a terminal tab
- another vim instance running in another terminal tab,

each vim instance editing a different file.

Here's what I mean by 'weird'.
Whenever I type something, one or more lines like below will be output and the page gets scrolled down a little.

> ,47
> 7
> 78,47         25%
> 7,23
> 6,5
> 7,23
> 8,47
> 80
> 1,0-1
> 2,47
> 3,0-1
> 6,42
> 7,47
> 8,3
> 9,4
> 90
> 2,0-1
> 3,47
> 2,0-1
> 1,47
> 89
> 8,3
> 7,4
> 6,42
> 5,0-1
> 2,47
> 1,0-1
> 0,47
> 79
> 7,23
> 6,5
> 5,38
> 4,47
> 3,34
> 2,25

And the commands that I'm trying to type i.e. `:q!` will be jumbled up with this gibberish above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Might want to edit the question and incorporate the additional details there.

Comment: I wonder if this is a curses/TERM problem